# Mono.Debugger.Soft - Exceptionhandling

Tags: debugging, mono

I am just working with the Mono.Debugger.Soft API to control the soft debugger of a mono application.
I enabled all events which i need with the following code:

```
vm.EnableEvents(EventType.AssemblyLoad,
    EventType.ThreadStart,
    EventType.ThreadDeath,
    EventType.AssemblyUnload,
    EventType.UserBreak,
    EventType.Exception,
    EventType.UserLog,
    EventType.KeepAlive,
    EventType.TypeLoad);
```

That works pretty nice, but if i have an caught or also uncaught exception the Exception Event is risen. But unfortunattly i dont know if the exception which has just risen in the application is a handled or an unhandled one with a surrounding try/catch?

Does anyone knows how i can determine if the exception is an unhandled one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution, just create two distinct exception requests:

```
        unhandledExceptionRequest = vm.CreateExceptionRequest(null, false, true);
        unhandledExceptionRequest.Enable();

        handledExceptionRequest = vm.CreateExceptionRequest(null, true, false);
        handledExceptionRequest.Enable();
```